# Autocmd in visual mode neovim for syncing selection to X11 buffer

Tags: lua, neovim

I want anything that I select in visual mode to go to the X11 buffer. My ideal workflow would be something like:

1. I enter visual mode by pressing v (or V or ctrl V etc.)
2. Select some text by some usual movements hjkl, wb or similar
3. Outside of the terminal I do a middle click (click with the scroll-wheel) and the selection from 2 is pasted where I pressed

I can get something almost like this with e.g. a keymap:
`vim.keymap.set("v",  "<leader>y", [["*ygv]])` and then adding a step between (2) and (3) where I press `<leader>y`.

My actual question is for how to make this yanking (while keeping visual selection (gv in my example keymap)) happen automatically.

Probably I would like something like an autocommand but I don't know the right events to be watching. Something that appears to kind-off work is:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"CursorMoved", "ModeChanged"}, {
    callback = function()
        local mode = vim.fn.mode(false)
        if mode == "v" or mode == "V" or mode == "^V" then
            vim.cmd([["*y]])
        end
    end,
})
```

but there are some problems:

- it might be a bit aggressive in how often it runs
- "^V" is not the right character to match against
- it messes up `:V` as the the initial line selection is removed (but adding `gv` to the command didn't seem to work)

What would be a better approach?

I'm running nvim v0.9.4 on gnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want that standard X11 feature when any visual selection updates PRIMARY selection atom (while CLIPBOARD is used with control-c or similar). Btw. gvim built for gtk/X11 supports this feature natively (named autoselection or such).

However, with nvim the situation is more complicated. The application is built for terminal and does not have any specific gtk or X11 code. The OS clipboard access is done usually by executing an external application such as xclip or xsel.

So, technically, you maybe could trap CursorMoved event and then (while the current mode is visual, of course) keep updating "star" register per each invocation. But, honestly, I don't think that's a good idea.

Such feature could possibly be implemented by some of nvim gui shells (nvim-qt, etc.) internally. But I'm not aware of anything like that done.

Also, consider that analogue of PRIMARY selection was not included into Wayland core. So it exists only as an extra feature in Gnome/Wayland implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the extra keywords to search for found this issue discussing the same thing https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2325

Comment: Would you like to add any motivation for why you don't think that is a good idea?

Comment: @VRehnberg Not afraid of lagging?

Comment: Of course, but I it wasn't apparent to me from your text that that was your worry or if you had any other motivation for your statement.   I'm on the fence whether I should accept your answer as correct or not. Though, it does bring some good context for why a good solution might not exist so I guess I'll accept it for now.

Comment: @VRehnberg The code fits within a line and is totally trivial. You need a minute or so to check this.

Comment: Yes, but that I had tried that I thought was apparent from the question all along (perhaps not). That it wasn't completely satisfactory is why I asked if there was any better solution. Your answer I've only evaluated on the grounds that it was a negative answer of "No, there is probably no better solution, here is why". The paragraph where you write something like "I don't think [your existing solution] is a good idea." was mostly bonus but would still have been worthwhile if it had some additional motivation for why it wasn't a good idea.

Comment: @VRehnberg Well, maybe I'm exaggerate things a little. I checked that on Windows and it looks like adding only few percent of CPU load while using default winyank. And swithing to my neoclip plugin with direct access to OS API or to the exported gui shell's methods makes the difference even unnoticeable. So take it mostly as my personal reluctance to load CursorMoved with potentially heavy code. But, nowadays, spawning even a dozen of new processes per second does not make CPU to sweat.